# Flutter: How do I show an AlertBox as soon as my network image is loaded and only for once after app opens

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to show an image on my screen, in an `AlertBox`. I am fetching the image from the network and then displaying it in the UI. I have a variable `announcementImage`, which is fetching data from API and stores the `url` in the variable. I want, as soon as I receive the image URL and as soon as the image loads, my `AlertBox` should appear. And this should happen only once, i.e. after the app starts. It should not appear again after I come back from another page.

Here is the code of initState -

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("\n \n \n \n Started initialize \n \n");
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero).then((value) {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext buildContext) {
          const double iconSize = 27;
          return LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (context, constraints) => AlertDialog(
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              elevation: 0,
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              content: SizedBox(
                width: constraints.maxWidth * .75,
                height: constraints.maxHeight * .71,
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: ValueListenableBuilder(
                        valueListenable: announcementImage,
                        builder: (BuildContext context, String? url, Widget? child) {
                          return Image.network(
                            url??"",
                            width: constraints.maxWidth * .72 - iconSize,
                            height: constraints.maxHeight * .72 - iconSize,
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),

                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          ),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                            child: const Icon(
                              Icons.close,
                              size: iconSize,
                              color: colorPrimary,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    });
  }
```